# How to handle massive http request with java?

Tags: spring-boot, ignite, in-memory-database, thorntail, foundationdb

We have a project in java platfrom that handle milion http request per day. We have exprience in jee platfrom with wildfly as app sever also we use relational database , my question is how we can use in memory solution with support acid transaction , also select framework for supporting microservice pattern?  How to select good in memory db and good app server ? Also use spring boot or use jee standard ( use thorntail ,...)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good question for StackOverflow, but one thing I can answer is: if you have experience with WildFly, then Thorntail will have (mostly) the same operational characteristics, as it's just WildFly under the hood.

Comment: Do you have exprience with in memory database such as apache ignite?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ignite in two deployment modes - either as an in-memory data grid that is deployed on top of your relational database or in-memory database on its own with Ignite persistence enabled.

Both modes support all the Ignite APIs including distributed transactions. Both provide unlimited scalability in RAM plus with Ignite persistence you can scale horizontally on disk.

So, basically, it’s up to you to select the mode. Refer to this page that shows some of the advantages of Ignite persistence:https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store

Comment: Thanks for answer, in other hand is there any idea about thorntail to handle massive http requests?